# What causes a NullPointerException during finalize() of a FileInputStream in Android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fileinputstream

I'm converting our application from using external files (accessed using filenames) to internal ones (accessed using `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` objects).  However, I am getting a rather weird error: on `finalize()`, the `FileInputStream`s are sometimes throwing a `NullPointerException`.

logcat tells me:

```
Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
java.lang.NullPointerException:
at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:133)
at java.io.FileInputStream.finalize(FileInputStream.java:156)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Looking at the [FileInputStream source on docjar.com](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/FileInputStream.java.html) it seems possible this could be cause by a null `FileDescriptor`; however, I want to be able to pass bad filenames to my `FileInputStream` constructors and catch `FileNotFoundException` since this is all I can do with the Android internal system (short of measuring the filename against each entry in `Context#fileList()`).  Is there a way to work round this problem?

NB obviously an exception in a finalizer isn't causing me any actual crashes, but I feel like I should try and tidy this up.

Answer (score 1):

You should be manually calling close on your streams because finalize isn't guaranteed to be called. In which case (unless closeLock is nulled before finalize is called) the NPE will be avoided.

If you're using Context.openFileInput/Output; you can check if the file exists by:

```
File f = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
if(!f.exists()) {
    //ohnoes!
}
```

If you're using AssetManager.open(); I think you can do something like:

```
File f = new File("file:///android_asset/" + filename);
if(!f.exists()) {
    //ohnoes!
}
```

Comment: I am calling `close()`—this seems to have been happening when the streams were improperly initialized.  Wouldn't this just shift the NPE to the method I call `close()` from, though? Thanks also for the tip about file existence :)